# Moving records in sql based on HTML form input

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, forms

I am trying to move records a database based on the input of a form but seem to be encountering an issue. I have tried the below but it is not executing the command on the database. It needs to read in a value for decision and carry out a query based on the decision.Can anyone spot the issue here? I have ran the query in SQL Server and it works.

HTML form code:

```
<!--Other Form-->
 <center>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="dLG.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete ?');">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
          <label for="License Group ID">Enter the License Group ID that you wish to delete</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
          <input type="number" name="LicenseGroupID" placeholder="LicenseGroupID">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete License Group">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

php :

```
<html>
<?php 
$serverName = "x";
$options = array(  "UID" => "x",  "PWD" => "x",    "Database" => "x");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);
if( $conn === false )
 {
 echo "Could not connect.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }  
$License_Group_ID = $_POST['LicenseGroupID']; 

$query = "DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_license_group
        OUTPUT 
        deleted.License_Group_ID,
        deleted.Vendor_Name,
        deleted.License_Version,
        deleted.Edition,
        deleted.Operating_System,
        deleted.Quantity            
        INTO dbo.tbl_license_group_delete(License_Group_ID, Vendor_Name, License_Version,Edition,Quantity)
        WHERE  License_Group_ID = '$License_Group_ID'; " ;        
       $params1 = array($License_Group_ID);                       
       $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params1);
       sqlsrv_close($conn);
       ?>
       </html>
```

Comment: It will be a real help if you could provide the error stack.

Comment: apologies im new to this , when I submit the form , it moves to the php file but does not interact with the database. The parameters display in the url which is something I noticed different from similar functions I have which work. Is this what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Default form method is GET, not POST. If you want to use POST (and you should in this case), use:

```
<form action=".." method="post"  onsubmit="...">
...
</form>
```

Second problem is with the $query string. It should use parameters like this:

```
$query = "DELETE ... WHERE  License_Group_ID = ?; " ;
```

PS: Its better to use PDO than sqlsrv_* functions.